# Is marriage certificate required to prove ties to home country?

Tags: visas, canada, proof-of-ties

I am about to submit an application for a Canadian visa and I want to add my Marriage certificate as proof of Ties to my home country. Is this really a necessity as a supporting document?

Comment: Are you claiming your wife is a dependent relative? If so, and she's not travelling with you, then it could be useful documentary support. Is there a reason why you wouldn't want to send it?

Comment: Not exactly. And yes shes not making the trip with me for now. Basically i was asking as to what i would add to make a stronger application.@ReddHerring

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a required document for you to submit, but it would be helpful to prove ties to your home country, as it shows you have a wife who is staying behind during your trip who you financially support. Your case doesn't get automatically dismissed if you do not include it, but it could help your application.

Comment: The marriage certificate does not show that the spouse lives anywhere in particular, much less that she is staying anywhere at any particular time.  By itself, it isn't particularly useful.  In combination with other evidence, it might be.